# Xamarin.Android Archive Not Appearing

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

My android archives and app disappeared from archive manager. Building or Archiving for Publication would complete without error. However the archives wouldn't appear in the list even when showing all. I tried renaming the project and modifying settings, non of which worked. I found the archives were not appearing in the typical "Machintosh HD - Users -  - Library - Developer - Xamarin - Archives - " folder. They were instead appearing in an adjacent folder called ErroredArchives.

This was around the time I deleted all my archives for that app through archive manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that my Release | ARM platform configuration won't successfully generate an archive. Using Release (Blank aka AnyCPU) or Release | x86 does. This is despite the fact that my x86 and ARM configurations are exactly the same. Not sure why it wouldn't work.

I thought the following worked but I had a different platform selected. Resolve the issue by duplicating the solution folder and using that new copy instead.

Comment: You can mark your answer .So that more people can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem of my project building and archiving without error. My archives also appeared in the ErrorArchives folder.

For me this was caused by an empty `<AndroidManifest></AndroidManifest>` tag in my .csproj file, located in amongst the tags for the configuration I was using for archiving.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Preview|AnyCPU' ">
  ...
  <AndroidManifest></AndroidManifest>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Removing this tag resolved the problem.